# Architecture for multiple http requests

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous

I read a lot of text about creating normal architecture for asynchronous operations.
But i still have problems.

Most of all examples on web showing connectivity to web-service with the help of AsyncTask.
So we have troubles using this simple architecture with recreating Activity, when device change it's orientation with landscape to normal and vice versa.
Also we have problems when our task has been started but user pressed back and we lost all information about current AsyncTask.

I want to build architecture where you can simply execute some requests and have callback to activity it's called after the operation ends.
I am planning to use service for background operations and `ThreadExecutor` for handling operations.

Here is the most informative link about threads and background operations i had found.
http://www.slideshare.net/andersgoransson/efficient-android-threading

So now, can you tell me some good code examples for implementing this approach? It can be without any comments(not tutorial mb just project on `Github`), but with code, to see how this can be implemented.

Comment: Our company developing communication framework, where we made the same approach - made our own task management. We use ExecutorService for execution. Also we made several modes of execution: some tasks must be executed in order (for example, when there are several requests on the same remote host), or in parallel.

Comment: @АндрейМосквичёв Do you have some source code examples which you can share with us?

Comment: Sources are proprietary. I can give you a brief description about what we made.

Comment: @АндрейМосквичёв It will be great. I am interested to read this.

Comment: Wrote a description of how we made it. I hope this help you. If you have any questions, feel free to ask them.

Comment: Check out Spring for Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our company is developing mobile-web-desktop communication framework, where we have made our own async tasks management.

Framework operates with remote devices, and each transaction between local and remote device is performed in Transaction (extended analog of AsyncTask).

TransactionManager class hold all transactions and responsible for their execution. It has single-thread and cached thread pool ExecutorService. If transaction is marked explicitly, that it can be run in parallel - it runs on cached thread pool (multithreaded mode), overwise it runs on single-thread executor. It's made because not all transactions can run multithreaded, and can be side effects, if they run in multithreaded mode (for example, when there are several transactions, that change the state of local or remote device).

How to create single- cached- or fixed ExecutorService can be found here: [Executors](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html)

TransactionManager itself is located in Service. Service connected to all other app's components by local binding, as described here [Bound Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)

Each transaction has unique identifier, participating device, message (the step now performed, such as "connecting", "downloading", "uploading"), progress and state.
State can be NotStarted, Started, Error, Finished. 
Message is used to show it in the UI - what is now performed.
Unique identifier (uid) is used to find transaction or to send transaction info to another activity just by sending it's uid in intent.

We solved screen rotate problem as follows:

```
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

            // transaction manager holds all transactions
    TransactionManager transactionManager = commService.getTransactionManager();

    String lsTransactionId = savedInstanceState.getString(LS_TRANSACTION_ID);
    if (lsTransactionId != null) {
        lsTransaction = (OutgoingTransaction<FileItem[]>) transactionManager.getTransactionById(lsTransactionId);
        // update UI according to transaction state
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

            // if we have runnng transaction - store it's id to bundle
    if (lsTransaction != null) {
        outState.putString(LS_TRANSACTION_ID, lsTransaction.getId());
    }
}
```

Transaction class has abstract method perform that make actual work (download or upload data, etc) - analog of AsyncTask's doInBackground method.

Transaction has listener to receive it's events:

```
public interface TransactionListener<T> {
/**
 * Called when transaction is started.
 */
void started();

/**
 * Called when transaction message is posted by Transaction.setMessage call.
 * @param message message
 */
void message(String message);

/**
 * Called when transaction is finished.
 * @param result transaction result
 */
void finished(T result);

/**
 * Called when transaction is cancelled.
 */
void cancelled();

/**
 * Called when transaction error is occurred.
 * @param thr throwable indicating an error
 */
void error(Throwable thr);

/**
 * Called on transaction progress.
 * @param value progress value
 * @param total progress total
 */
void progress(long value, long total);
}
```

And here is other thing - to make listener methods execute on UI thread, we made helper class AndroidTransactionListener, that use Handler.post to execute the above methods on ui thread. About Handler you can read here: [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

Comment: Thank you for response. Maybe later i will try to write my own framework for correct using long duration operations. 
Now I decide to use Robospice, because of it's caching requests, great tool from the box.

Answer (score 0):

Volley library can do what you want. If you want own library there are sources as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Robospice for this. It has listeners you attach to at a service level essentially in onResume(). You fire away tasks to it and it will do them for you. It's a considerable amount of work to setup but I found it easier than mountains of manual threading.

It also supports caching if you have a well defined responses.